# How can I get Iron router data context in template helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, datacontext

I'm a newbie to Meteor. I set the data context in iron:router as follows:

```
Router.route('/:index', {
   name:'randomText',
   template: 'textsRandom',
   data: function(){
      textcol: Text.findOne({index: this.params.index})
   }
}
```

And in template textsRandom, I want to access `textcol` in the helper because I want to change the color of specific words in the text later.

```
Template.textRandom.helpers({
   mytexts: function(){
      var texts = //code here to get textcol in router.js
      //get some words from texts and change their colors
      return texts;
   }
｝）
```

Any suggestions about how to do this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router is setting the data context of the route to an object. You can access the object in the helper as `this`. Since you want the `textcol` key of that object, then just:

```
Template.textRandom.helpers({
   mytexts: function(){
      return this.textcol;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
// router
function(){
   return {
      textcol: Text.findOne({index: this.params.index})
   };
}

// helper
var texts = this.textcol;
```